Ubuntu Software Centre starts but does not load
The app starts, there is activity in the Activity panel, but no windows etc appear and activity stops.
Newly-installed Ubuntu 20.4, Dell Inspiron 5759

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
